# Is it possible to install/use multiple PC-Speakers?

Tags: audio, speakers, sound-card, ms-dos, freedos

First a bit of context: by 'PC-Speakers' I do not mean standard 3.5mm jack based stereo speakers. What I am reffering to is the 4-pin 255 frequency speaker connected directly to the motherboard.

Now a bit of information about the current set up, and my goal: after many years of using DOSBox I grew tired of it and decided I wanted to go back to genuine DOS. So I dug through my collection of spare and old hardware and frankensteined together a retro tower. The tower in question is using a 3.0GHz Pentium D CPU, with 512MB RAM and an on-board GPU with VGA support up to 1440x900 and 64MB of VRAM. External drive is a USB1.1 floppy diskette drive (3.5").

Now I installed a copy of FreeDOS on this machine rather than MS-DOS or PC-DOS because of the Extended Memory Support, however once I had finished configuring everything I realized I had neglected one very important piece of hardware: a soundcard. Seeing as I don't have money to buy one at the moment and I don't have one laying around I am stuck using the PC-Speaker for sound effects in games and with no music.

So here's my question: given that the MoBo in question has it's PC-Speaker directly soldered on rather than via a wired connection, would it be possible (assuming that there was a four pin connecter available on the MoBo) to install a second PC-Speaker? More importantly if this could be done, would it be possible to use both PC-Speakers at once within games, and other software, to either allow for a higher number of mixed sound FX at once, or to use one to provide basic sound FX and the other to play low-quality MIDI sample based music in place of regular in-game tracks?

TL;DR: could one hypothetically use two internal PC-Speakers as a low-quality replacement for a stereo-capable soundcard when playing games in DOS?

P.S.: Please do not suggest DOSBox, DOSEMU or any other DOS Emulator, I have no desire to use these things. Thanks!

Comment: short answer: no. long answer: no

Comment: I read "retro" and imagine 486 at most – and BOOM! 3.0GHz Pentium D CPU with 512MB RAM. :)

Comment: I guess if a motherboard had soldered on speaker along with four pin connector, then the two would be electrically connected.

Comment: **IporSircer**: No explanation as to why? Disregarding then. **KamilMaciorowski**: Indeed it's odd to think about but at this point the early-to-mid Pentium series CPUs have been around long enough that I personally consider them to be retro, admittedly it's no m68k or 286-486, but the D series is nearly 12 years old after all. As far as the RAM goes, we do live in a day and age where GPUs on their own have up to 24GB of VRAM so... :P Anyway, you make a good point, I'll try playing DOOM with VirtualSoundBlaster enabled and if I'm lucky it will be an inherent result of the configuration.

Comment: Speakers have impedance, most "PC sound systems" have a plug to an amp and that amp handle the impedance matching etc. A hardwired speaker to the motherboard is going to have the motherboard handle amplification etc and this is going to be a simple budget circuit designed for a specific type of speaker. If you wire up more than one, you change the impedance. As far as "is this good or bad", that depends. RE: stereo. "NO" you will only ever get mono over *n*-speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PC Speaker interface can only control one speaker - see [osdev.org for sample code](http://wiki.osdev.org/PC_Speaker).  So there's no native way to do what you want.

Comment: Well, in that case it looks like I'm stuck buying a soundcard. Any suggestions? I'm looking at the Sound Blaster Live! right now. It has to be PCIx16 or PCI Express and needs to have either native or legacy DOS compatibility, would the Live! be a good choice?

Comment: Alas, I'm not sure, but the hardware recs stack exchange should be able to help you.